# Creating Custom user type just like custom post

Tags: users, user-roles, user-meta

How to create custom user types (User Role) just like the custom post types.

For example:

User Role 1: Having a normal profile field.
User Role 2: Having 3 extra fields in the profile.

2 different set of users with different user_meta fields.

Comment: Please improve your question, see [ask]. Plugin recommendations are *off topic*, see [On Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, [Roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) are in many ways custom user types and you can add meta fields specific to roles. For example...

```
function is_my_user_role($id = null) {
  global $profileuser;
  if (empty($profile) && !empty($id)) $profileuser = get_user_to_edit($id);
  return (in_array('myrole',$profileuser->roles)) ? true : false;
}

function my_user_fields($profileuser) {
  if (!is_my_user_role()) return false;

  // HTML for the fields
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'my_user_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'my_user_fields');
```

And essentially the same check when you go to save the data.